# implementing quick sort only on one half of the array

Tags: java, arrays, quicksort

I have an excercise in which I have to improve an algorithem. This algorithem takes an array and puts the evens in the left side (SORTED) and the odds in the right side (NOT-SORTED).
The algorithem is inefficient so I have to improve it.

Here is the original code of the excercise, the one I have to "improve":

```
public void what (int [] arr) {
    int temp;
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i]%2 == 0) {
            temp = arr[i];
            for (int j=i; j>0; j--)
                arr[j] = arr[j-1];
            arr[0] = temp;
    }
}
```

I wanted to implement quick sort algorithem on this excercise, but the problem is I don't know how the use the pivot: usually, the pivot is the median, the number half of the array is smaller and the other half is bigger.

The problem here is that the left part has to be evens and the right part, odds.

I have to implement this "sorting" in an efficiency less than O(n^2).

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a specific question about a problem you're having writing code to do this?

Comment: It's weird to have a method named `what`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - wonders of university example exams :)

Comment: @Alan That explains it ;)

Comment: @EngineerDollery - I haven't gotton so much progress. I don't excatly want A code solution, just an idea to a differrent algorithem.

Comment: If you have some extra space, how about, keeping odd and even numbers in the separate array. Sorting even array and finally merging them?

Comment: @zerocool - that would be great, but I can't allocate any more space than I recieved as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having two indexes, one starts from the begining (i=-1)and one from the end(j=a.length). increment i and put the even numbers and decrement j to put the odd numbers. Once the iteration is complete, i would point to the last element of the even elements. Apply quick sort taking middle element as pivot(ie from 0 to i).

Comment: this sounds interesting, but quick sort is O(nlogn) already, and this way I would add another time moving through the array. Is it more efficient than O(n^2)? hmmm... it is O(nlogn) still, right?

Comment: Considering the fact that you do not have extra space, under the worst case (when all elements are even) yes this is going to take nlogn. Having said that i dont see how can you avoid it, as you want to sort these elements and these elements do not have any particular behavior ( these can be any integer numbers). My point is, end of the day you have to apply sorting and its going to take that much of time.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion one: Pass linearly through the array and split it in two - even elements and odd elements. This takes Theta(n) time. As you are doing linear sweep and you check each element anyways you can find out which one is the biggest and which one is the smallest element. Then you can implement counting sort on the array of even integers. Counting sort examples:

[Counting sort interactive](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/Csc517.091/workbook/countingsort.html)
[Counting sort video](http://youtu.be/_q0OOXo4l7E)

Counting sort running time is O(n) amortised so your overall running time of the algorithm would be O(n).

Suggestion two: If you wish to use quicksort, threat every odd value as + infinity and it would naturally go at the end of the list, without comparing. If you happen to choose odd pivot, just put it at the end, and try again. I suggest using random pivot rather than first/last.

Comment: trying to understand :)
1) Since the input can be of any range( my assumption, as problem does not say anything about the range of the input), do you think counting sort is a good idea to use.
2)I am not sure about what you are trying to say, as much as i understand, you want to apply quick sort of the complete array, why to do that when u need to only sort even number?

Comment: Sorry for late reply..

As I said in order to use counting sort you'd have to know the range. Splitting the array in odd and even parts would always involve linearly passing though it, which makes it possible to identify the range with no extra computational cost.

The suggestion to use quicksort without splitting was because you can sort only the even elements without having to do the extra work of identifying them first.

Answer (score 0):

As @zerocool suggested, implemented by code:

```
private static int medianEven(int [] arr){
        int i=-1, j=arr.length; int temp=0; int w=0;
        while ((w<j)){
            if (arr[w]%2==0){
                i++;
                w++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp=arr[j-1];
                arr[j-1]=arr[w];
                arr[w]=temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;

    }
```

after that, called quickSort method from arr[0] to arr[i]:

```
quicksort(arr,0,i);
```

Thank you for the advice.